# How do I restore a delete windows 7 cached profile?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-profiles

I deleted the wrong profile in Windows 7 and now I need to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome to Superuser, Joe.**

When removing the user profile you chose to delete files you are out of luck. Otherwise, if you chose to keep them, the user's folder will still be listed under `C:\Users`.

If the later is the case, you can create a new profile and copy pertinent data from the old folder to the new one.